# Excel VBA code for simple formula between cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, range

[image]

I need a code for these orders:

1. Go to first blanks cell in column C.
2. Calculate the number in column D minus 14 and do it as long there is a number right to the cell in D (there is blanks in column D)
3. Copy the result in column C and paste it as values to Column B.
   note: I need it to stay in original rows.

```
OP_wb.Sheets("Optic Main").Activate 
Dim FirstRow As Range 
Dim LastRow As Range
Set FirstRow = Range("C1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
 
Range("E1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, -2).Select
Range(FirstRow, LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=(c4-14)"`
```

Comment: @TimWilkinson
that is what I have:

`OP_wb.Sheets("Optic Main").Activate

Range("C1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Activate

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1]-14"`

Comment: here is where i stuck now: `Dim FirstRow As Range
Dim LastRow As Range


Set FirstRow = Range("C1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
Set LastRow = Range("E1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, -2)



            Range(FirstRow, LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC4-14)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

1.

```
Set FirstRow = Range("C1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
Set lastrow = Range("E1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, -2)

Range("E1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, -2).Select
```

2.

```
Range(FirstRow, lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=(c4-14)"
```

3.

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=ActiveCell.Range("A1:A" & lastrow)
```

hope this helps